# How to find a basis of a subspace of P3

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **V** = **P3** and **U** be a subspace of **V** where **U** = { (a-c)x^2 - (a+b+c)x + (c-a) | a, b, c ∈ **R**)

How do I find a basis of **U**?

I know how to find a basis of a set of vectors, but I'm not sure how do to find it of a subspace like this.

I tried just choosing a set of polynomials in **U** and then finding a basis of this set to which I got the basis { -3x , -3-6x+3x^2 }. But am I right in saying this is only a basis of the set I chose, and not of **U** itself?

If so, how would I go about finding a spanning set of **U** so I could then check for linear independence?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Visit following link for MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Note that $$(a-c)x^2 - (a+b+c)x + (c-a)=a(x^2-x-1)-bx+c(-x^2-x+1)$$

Clearly $\{ x^2-x-1, -x, -x^2-x+1\}$ spans $U$, try to check if it is linearly independent. If it is not, find a subset that is linearly independent and still span the $U$. Clearly the first two elements are not multiple of each other.

Comment: Thanks for this, am I right in assuming the first polynomial is supposed to be (x^2 - x - 1) rather then (x^2 - x - x)?

Comment: ah yes, you are right, I made a mistake. thanks.